# Can indefinite article refer to anything within a list?

Tags: grammar, articles

Please, help..

"There are pens on a table. Take a pen and write down the text"
 = Take one of those pens?

"Here are some books. I know you like reading. Take a book and read it"
 = Take one of those books?

Can the indefinite article here refer to instances within a list only, not suggesting instances that are outside the list of pens or books I talk about?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much what "indefinite article" means; an article that is indefinite. Unless there's something else narrowing the choice ("Take a pen that has blue or black ink") then any one meets the criteria.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunatelly , I don't get your point. I still don't understand if the indefinite article can refer only to the items within a list.. Like here, a person has several TVs at home: "Welcome to my house. If you want to entertain yourself, use a TV". Any TV within a house and not any TV at all? I think it is the context that makes it clear. Saying the last sentence is the same like "Use a TV I have". It is also worth saying, that if there are several windows in a room, people say: "Close a window", but that doesn't mean any in the World...

Comment: Any TV that makes sense in the context. If you've just said "All the rooms have televisions" then that gives a context.

Comment: But isn't it the same with the examples about books and pens? I was confused by your phrase: "without anything narrowing the choice, anything meets criteria" I assume the context makes it clear what items I refer to. I refer to any of the pens on my table. So saying "take a pen" means the same as "take any of those pens, not any in the World." Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, that gives a context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The likely interpretation of those examples is to take one of pens or books offered. It can imagine it could be used with the other meaning, but I can't think of a context in which it would be likely.